# S3: Allow download of files for those who have some token

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to only allow download from Amazon's S3 for anyone who have some token and a link to some file in my bucket?

This token, for example, can be generated by my upload backend server, and appended to the uploaded file.

What possibilities do I have here?

**Edit**

When I said download from S3, I mean directly from S3 not through my server, only upload happens through server

Comment: Have you [read the documentation on pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)?

Comment: Yes, the signed URLs expire after some time, and you will have to re-generate the URL again. I don't need this, I need permanent access to the files on S3 for non-users using some token, if any

Comment: There is no built-in, non-expiring, token-based access control mechanism.  Your application, however, could -- upon recognizing a token in a request -- build a signed URL with a short expiration, and send a `302` redirect to it, so the download is still from S3 directly.

Comment: I can give it long expiration time to act as a non-expiring one, but, can I revoke/force-to-expire the url?

Comment: Expiration times are limited to 7 days with Signature V4, much longer with Signature V2.  Revoking a signed URL is only possible by revoking the AWS Access Key ID used to sign the request.

Comment: Here are some ways to bypass the 7 days limit on signature V4. https://medium.com/@django.course/to-avoid-the-limitation-of-7-day-window-for-pre-signed-urls-as-mentioned-by-bryant-biggs-e921da4ea96e

Answer (score 2):

You can generate presigned URLs using [minio-py](https://github.com/minio/minio-py) like this:

```
from minio import Minio

client = Minio('s3.amazonaws.com',
               access_key='YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
               secret_key='YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY')

downloadURL = client.presigned_get_object('mybucket', 'myobject')
```

You can use downloadURL on browser to download files directly from S3.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, just warp the access with some authentication from your end

```
var backendTokenAuthenticator = require('/auth')
app.get('/download/:file',function(req, res){
    if(req.query.token && req.params.file){
        backendTokenAuthenticator(req.query.token,req.params.file,function(err,isAuth){
            if(err){
                res.status(500).end()
            }else if(!isAuth){
                res.status(403).end('permission denied')
            }else{
                var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                s3.getObject({ 
                    Bucket: "myBucket",
                    Key: req.params.file 
                },
                function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
                        res.status(404).end('File not found');
                    } else {
                        res.setHeader('Content-Length', data.ContentLength);
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
                        res.end(data.Body)
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }else{
        res.status(403).end('token must be supplied')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check my edit in the question